# Symfony mocking repository for testing

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to mock a repository containing all modules, and it has a method called findAll() that returns all elements from that repository. I cant seem to be able to pull any data from the mocked repository. Any ideas how I could fix it?

Mocking repository:

```
$moduleRepository = $this->createMock(ModuleRepository::class);
```

Trying to use method from ModuleRepository class called findAll() that returns all elements from the repo in an array.

```
$moduleRepository->expects($this->any())
        ->method('findAll')
        ->willReturn([]);
```

Thats what I get when I print $moduleRepository:

```
Mock_ModuleRepository_f6bead1c Object
(
    [_entityName:protected] => 
    [_em:protected] => 
    [_class:protected] => 
    [__phpunit_originalObject:Mock_ModuleRepository_f6bead1c:private] => 
    [__phpunit_returnValueGeneration:Mock_ModuleRepository_f6bead1c:private] => 1
    [__phpunit_invocationMocker:Mock_ModuleRepository_f6bead1c:private] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\InvocationHandler Object
        (
            [matchers:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\InvocationHandler:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher Object
                        (
                            [invocationRule:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher:private] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Rule\AnyInvokedCount Object
                                (
                                    [invocations:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Rule\InvocationOrder:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [afterMatchBuilderId:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher:private] => 
                            [afterMatchBuilderIsInvoked:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher:private] => 
                            [methodNameRule:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher:private] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Rule\MethodName Object
                                (
                                    [constraint:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Rule\MethodName:private] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MethodNameConstraint Object
                                        (
                                            [methodName:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MethodNameConstraint:private] => findAll
                                            [exporter:PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint:private] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [parametersRule:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher:private] => 
                            [stub:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher:private] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Stub\ReturnStub Object
                                (
                                    [value:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Stub\ReturnStub:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [matcherMap:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\InvocationHandler:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [configurableMethods:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\InvocationHandler:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => findAllModuleRoutes
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\SimpleType Object
                                (
                                    [name:SebastianBergmann\Type\SimpleType:private] => array
                                    [allowsNull:SebastianBergmann\Type\SimpleType:private] => 
                                    [value:SebastianBergmann\Type\SimpleType:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => findAllQueryBuilderWithSearch
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\ObjectType Object
                                (
                                    [className:SebastianBergmann\Type\ObjectType:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\TypeName Object
                                        (
                                            [namespaceName:SebastianBergmann\Type\TypeName:private] => Doctrine\ORM
                                            [simpleName:SebastianBergmann\Type\TypeName:private] => QueryBuilder
                                        )

                                    [allowsNull:SebastianBergmann\Type\ObjectType:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => findListResults
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\SimpleType Object
                                (
                                    [name:SebastianBergmann\Type\SimpleType:private] => array
                                    [allowsNull:SebastianBergmann\Type\SimpleType:private] => 
                                    [value:SebastianBergmann\Type\SimpleType:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => createQueryBuilder
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => createResultSetMappingBuilder
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [5] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => createNamedQuery
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [6] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => createNativeNamedQuery
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [7] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => clear
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [8] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => find
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [9] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => findAll
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [10] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => findBy
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [11] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => findOneBy
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [12] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => count
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [13] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => __call
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [14] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => getClassName
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [15] => PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod Object
                        (
                            [name:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => matching
                            [returnType:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\ConfigurableMethod:private] => SebastianBergmann\Type\UnknownType Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [returnValueGeneration:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\InvocationHandler:private] => 1
            [deferredError:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\InvocationHandler:private] => 
        )

)
```

I tried it like this and the method actually gets called, but the repo has no data for it to find.

```
$moduleRepository->expects($this->any())
        ->method('findAll')
        ->willReturn([]);
    $myDebugVar = $moduleRepository->findAll();
    fwrite(STDERR, print_r($myDebugVar, TRUE));
```

Output:

```
Array()
```

Comment: Callin method `findAll` will retrun `[]`. It's written in your code. What else do you expect?

Comment: @u_mulder I'm trying to call method findAll that ModuleRepository has, that will return array. I understand that the call is bad, that's why I'm asking how to make it good.

Comment: Return array of what?

Comment: @u_mulder of all the modules in the ModuleRepository. Repository has around 30 modules, I need to get them all.

Comment: Do not mock the ModuleRepository. Just run and execute the query.

Comment: @u_mulder I'm trying to write a test for the findAll() method. I need to use it, not just get the elements from repository.

Comment: `->willReturn(['module1', 'module2', 'module3']);`

Comment: @u_mulder I need to pull actual data from repository, not to write it with my own hands. `Array
(
    [0] => module1
    [1] => module2
    [2] => module3
)
`

Comment: If you need to pull actual data from repository - then __why do you create a mock__? Do you understand what is __mock__?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `moduleRepository` will always return empty array, because you said to do it.

here you said to return an empty array `[]`:

```php
->willReturn([]);
```

from method `findAll`:

```php
->method('findAll')
```

---

There are some ways how to handle it, but for now, I recommend you to create a new database only for testing purposes, then create a new `.env.test` file which will extend the original `.env` file and use the exact repository instead of mock.

```
# .env.test.local
DATABASE_URL="mysql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1:3306/DB_NAME?serverVersion=5.7"
```

```php
namespace App\Tests\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

final class SomeTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private ?EntityManager $entityManager;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }


    public function testSomething()
    {
        //given
        $moduleRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ModuleRepository::class);

        //when
        $result = $moduleRepository->findAll(...);

        //then
        $this->assertEquals(...);
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        // doing this is recommended to avoid memory leaks
        $this->entityManager->close();
        $this->entityManager = null;
    }
}
```

Be sure you will fill up a new database with the data. It's a good idea to create fixtures for doing it automatically and clean up the database on `tearDown` method.

Comment: `$this->moduleRepository = self::$container->get(ModuleRepository::class);`


I get these errors:
`Incompatible types: Expected property of type '\App\Core\Repository\ModuleRepository', '\App\Core\Repository\ModuleRepository|null|object' provided `
and this one: 
`Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "monolog.handler.swift".
`

Comment: @Kacper I presume it should ne something like `self::$container->getEntityManager()->getRepository()`, I think repository is not defined as a service.

Comment: yeah, you're right, thanks @u_mulder. I will edit my previous post to your suggestion

Comment: `Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: The class 'App\Core\Repository\ModuleRepository' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Core\Entity, App\Epa\Entity, App\Minerals\Entity, App\UserManagement\Entity, App\HrManagement\Entity, App\Calculator\Entity, App\Catalogue\Entity, App\CountryManagement\Entity, App\Cart\Entity, App\Inventory\Entity, App\Log\Entity, App\Prices\Entity, Gesdinet\JWTRefreshTokenBundle\Entity
`

Why is the program looking for repository in the entity list ?

Comment: Please show me your repository, we have too little information to get you the correct answer.

Comment: @KacperMajczak `namespace App\Core\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToOne;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Core\Repository\ModuleRepository")
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="module")
 */`

thats how entity is connected with repo